# Recursive fraction (python)

Tags: python, function, recursion, fractions

given an integer x, the function should compute and return the following:

```
f(x) = 1/2 + 2/3 + ... + x/x+1
```

in my main, I have to display f(x) for values of x from 1 to 10, inclusively.

```
def recursive(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (x / (x + 1)) + recursive(x-1)

def main():
    print(recursive(10))   
main()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to recursion and don't quite understand it after using iteration for so long.

Comment: You are returning the number 2 + recursive(x-1) since x /x is 1. Use parentheses.

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: You shouldn't change your question by incorporating an answer someone posted into it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing brackets for x+1. Probably a typo.

your function should be below,

```
def recursive(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return x / (x + 1) + recursive(x-1)
```

Comment: Also, add a print just after `else` so the whole series gets printed

Comment: @Prakash Palnati May be I am wrong. But When i invoking `print(recursive(2))` it is returning 0. It should be 1/2 + 2/3 right. Ie,1.1666666666666665?

Comment: I tried fixing the brackets and added print for the else statement and I end up getting an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Fix the brackets and see if your result is good. For printing you refer answers below. sumthng like.. `"{}/{}".format(a-1, a)`

Answer (score 0):

there is one more correction about the data type currently its returning 0 we have to typecast it to float

```
def recursive(x):
if x == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return (float(x) / (x + 1)) + recursive(x-1)
```

def main():
    print(recursive(10))

Answer (score 0):

First you need parentheses in your denominator. Right now you are computing `(x/x) + 1 + recursive(x-1)`

```
def recursive(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return x/(x+1) + recursive(x-1)
```

Second, you should write separate code for printing `f(x)` from `1` to `10`. `print(recursive(10))` simply prints the value returned by `recursive(10)`, which is approximately `7.98`. What you want is a function that prints out a visual representation of the sum.

```
s = '1/2'
for i in range(2, 11): 
    s += ' + {}/{}'.format(i, i+1)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python also has a very useful "generator" function - yield, that can be used to develop recursive functions that actually return individual values for each call:

```
def factor(x: int):
    for a in range(x, 0, -1):
        yield((a-1)/a)

# Can be retrieved as a list or summed

l = [f for f in factor(10)]

s = sum(factor(10))


print("Result of {} is {}".format(l, s))
```

> Result of [0.9, 0.8888888888888888, 0.875, 0.8571428571428571, 0.8333333333333334, 0.8, 0.75, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 0.0] is 7.071031746031746

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood the question and  figured out the proper answer:

```
def recursive(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (float(x) / (x + 1)) + recursive(x-1)

def main():
    print(recursive(1))
    print(recursive(2))
    print(recursive(3))
    print(recursive(4))
    print(recursive(5))
    print(recursive(6))
    print(recursive(7))
    print(recursive(8))
    print(recursive(9))
    print(recursive(10))

main()
```

I was thinking that given a recursive function it should cycle and repeat itself (derp) I suppose I could do a for loop and a counter, but then I would be getting into iteration instead of recursion.